# Finding original width and height of AABB

Tags: flash, collision-detection, aabb

I have a rotated rectangle that I don't know the original width and height of. As the current width and height is just the bounding box encapsulating the rectangle, how would I find the actual width and height? thanks.

Comment: cant you unrotate it, measure width and height, then rotate back into position?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but I don't have any of the corners of the actual rectangle so I cant rotate them back. The only things I have are the mid point and the bounds of the bounding box.

Comment: If you dont know the angle of rotation, it will be complicated to calculate true bounds of rectangle. you may need to get help from http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know the angle of rotation, I just don't have the corners to rotate back by that angle. Thanks for the link, I'll try asking there.

Comment: dont understand what you mean by "dont have the corners"

Comment: To rotate the rectangle back to its original state, you need a point on the rectangle. I have the mid point so I can rotate that back, but since I don't know the co-ordinates of the Top Left and Bottom Right corners of the rotated rectangle, I cant rotate them back to get the width and height from them.

Comment: what form does your rectangle take? is it a display object or a variable? Can you post some code?

Comment: Its a Rectangle created when there's a collision between two display objects, one of these display objects is rotated, so the collision rectangle ends up also being rotated. And that's why I never know the original height and width of the rectangle as it was never rotated in the fist place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DisplayObject's [getBounds()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29)/[getRect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect%28%29) and pass the display object itself as a parameter. e.g. if `yourClip` is rotated, you try this:

`trace(yourClip.getBounds(yourClip));`.

It should be pretty close to the original dimensions. This works assuming you're using display objects (Sprites, MovieClips, etc.). Not sure if it helps, but [Mike Chambers' collision detection articles](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/) are pretty good.

In a comment you mentioned "Rectangle". Would that be [flash.geom.Rectangle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html) ?
If you prefer using geometry classes only, I suppose you could be using [flash.geom.Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) instances to keep track of coordinate systems. Transforming the corner points of the rectangle using Matrix's [transformPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#transformPoint%28%29) should be trivial. Also, you can move back and forth between coordinate systems using matrices again (and the [inverted](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#invert%28%29) versions as well). Still the DisplayObject class offers quite a few handy functions so you wouldn't need to do the matrix math yourself.

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty cool trick, but yeah the collision rectangle is a flash.geom.Rectangle that's made when a collision has occurred. Basically, my problem is I want to know which side of the rectangle was collided against. So I'm using the collision rectangle's bounds, for example, if it was a collision against the top I would check if the rectangle.top was between the y co-ords of the display objects top left and top right y co-ords. Since there's overlaps using that method, I was trying to find a point on the collision rectangle rather than the bounds of it.